# Send url with querystring with SmtpClient

Tags: c#, query-string, urlencode, smtpclient

Basic question here: I'm sending emails using the default SmtpClient of the .NET framework (3.5). The bodytype is HTML (IsBodyHtml = true) In the body I've added a url with two parameters in the querystring like so:

```
http://server.com/page.aspx?var1=foo&var2=bar
```

This get's encoded to:

```
http://server.com/page.aspx?var1=foo%26var2=bar (the ampersand is encoded as percent-26)
```

When doing a simple `Request["var2"]` I get 'null'.
What should I do to properly encode the ampersand in the mail message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
var client = new SmtpClient();
client.Host = "smtp.somehost.com";
var message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress("from@example.com");
message.To.Add(new MailAddress("to@example.com"));
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.Subject = "test";
string url = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("http://server.com/page.aspx?var1=foo&var2=bar");
message.Body = "<html><body><a href=\"" + url + "\">Test</a></body></html>";
client.Send(message);
```

Comment: Alright. It appears that Outlook Web Access is mangling the URL, not the SmtpClient or anything :( Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Use the [UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx) method. This will do all the encoding of your input string for you.